# HTML5/Cesium - making divs float over cesium map

Tags: html, cesiumjs

I am using cesium : http://cesiumjs.org/
and I wanted to make some divs float over a cesium map, but I can't get it to work.

I tried the following container/tag method at jsfiddle.net/j08691/dChUR/5/ - substituing the image by a cesium map div - but it doesn't seem to work - the "tag" div isn't shown.

Any help?

Comment: Have you tried adding a z-index to your divs?

Comment: Yes - tried it.
Didn't work. It something with cesium that blocks it, I think.

Comment: Could you post a link with a version using the censium map?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to add `position: absolute;` and either `top` or `bottom` to your CSS, because the widget also uses absolute positioning.  Adding this creates a new [stacking context](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Understanding_z_index/The_stacking_context), which overrides `z-index`.

Here's a working example, hit "Run Code Snippet" at the bottom of this:

```js
Cesium.Camera.DEFAULT_VIEW_FACTOR = 0;

var viewer = new Cesium.Viewer('cesiumContainer', {
  timeline: false,
  animation: false,
  navigationHelpButton: false
});

var skyAtmosphere = viewer.scene.skyAtmosphere;
var skyCheckbox = document.getElementById('skyCheckbox');

skyCheckbox.addEventListener('change', function() {
  viewer.scene.skyAtmosphere = skyCheckbox.checked ? skyAtmosphere : undefined;
}, false);
```

```css
html, body, #cesiumContainer {
  width: 100%; height: 100%; margin: 0; padding: 0; overflow: hidden;
  font-family: sans-serif; color: #edffff;
}
#controlPanel {
  position: absolute;
  top: 5px;
  left: 5px;
  background: rgba(42, 42, 42, 0.8);
  padding: 5px 8px;
  border-radius: 5px;
}
label {
  cursor: pointer;
}
label:hover span {
  text-decoration: underline;
}
```

```html
<link href="http://cesiumjs.org/releases/1.15/Build/Cesium/Widgets/widgets.css" 
      rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="http://cesiumjs.org/releases/1.15/Build/Cesium/Cesium.js">
</script>
<div id="cesiumContainer"></div>
<div id="controlPanel">
  This is a floating control panel<br/>
  with a translucent background color.
  <p>
    <label>
      <input id="skyCheckbox" type="checkbox" checked />
      <span>Enable atmospheric effect</span>
    </label><br/>
    <button class="cesium-button">Button 1</button>
    <button class="cesium-button">Button 2</button>
  </p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

To add to [emackey](https://stackoverflow.com/users/836708/emackey)'s answer, what I had to do in addition to adding `position: absolute` to my css was to add a `top:150px` or `bottom:150px`. Basically anything that will specify a position relative to the parent container.

Even though using the absolute position it is most likely being pushed down by the cesium widget since it takes up 100% height.

Comment: Oh good point, I'll edit my answer to add that.  Without `top` or `bottom`, the vertical positioning is automatic, which means it's down below the Cesium widget instead of overlaying it, possibly cropped off the bottom of the page.